# Aapt error Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a Aapt error in all of my Android projects. 
When searching for an solution I found using android.enableAapt2=false could help, but i'm constantly getting errors like;

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIndexedListIterator.next(AbstractIndexedListIterator.java:80)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.getOnlyElement(Iterators.java:315)
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(Iterables.java:263)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v1.AaptV1.makePackageProcessBuilder(AaptV1.java:202)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.makeValidatedPackage(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:67)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:807)
    ... 56 more
```

I already reinstalled Android Studio, Android SDK and i tried deleting my settings files. 
When i'm not using android.enableAapt2=false im getting

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$compile$0(QueueableAapt2.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:443)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:395)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:312)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)
```

I am using Android Studio 3.1.1 build 173.4697961.

edit: I also tried to clean the project, as well as running .gradlew clean, rebuild ect.

edit: I'm using Gradle 4.4 and Android Studio 3.1.1. I cleared the cache and restarted, also I deleted the .gradle/cache folder from my account

Comment: How did you reinstalled Android Studio and SDK ? Did you delete all the files associated with these two before installing ?

Comment: Yes I did. I deleted my SDK folder, my Android Studio settings and uninstalled Android Studio. Rebooted and downloaded everything to install it again

Comment: The first one is a bug in calling AAPT1. You shouldn't disable AAPT2 since AAPT1 will be disabled soon. To be able to find the issue that you have with AAPT2 you need to paste the full build log with the errors from AAPT2.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed it by reinstalling my PC. 
The problem was caused by having ë in my username.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same error, here's steps i followed to resolve it.

```
-update all files in app.gradle its asking for. 
- update all files in build. gradle its asking for. 
- invalidate cache and restart Android studio.
```

Aapt2 is enabled by default when you use android plugin for gradle 3.0. 
so open gradle.properties and add `android.enableAapt2=false`
as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWyT2.png

Comment: It's not asking for anything. I'm using Gradle 4.4 and Android Studio 3.1.1. I cleared the cache and restarted, also I deleted the .gradle/cache folder from my account

Comment: open gradle.properties and add android.enableAapt2=false

Answer (score -1):

this can happen if you edited String.xml file. reset Strings.xml

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: if you edit the generated String.xml by hand this error can happen.

Answer (score -1):

I guess by invalidating cache and restarting may fix your problem!